# Can gcc or clang inline functions that are not in the same compilation unit?

Tags: gcc, clang, inlining

Say I have a function with the inline keyword in a compilation unit.

If I have

```
// math.h
inline int sum(int x, int y);
```

and

```
// math.c
inline int sum(int x, int y)
{
   return x + y;
}
```

and

```
// main.c
#include "math.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return sum(argc,argc);
}
```

And building with

```
gcc -O3 -c math.c -o math.o
gcc -O3 -c main.c -o main.o
gcc math.o main.o
```

Will an optimizing compiler inline `sum`? Can gcc or clang inline functions from other compilation units?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/370237/whole-program-optimization

Comment: Don't create your own header `math.h` — it will be confused with the standard C `<math.h>` header sooner or later.  Ditto for other standard headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC can (and often will) inline functions from different TUs when you compile with LTO enabled. For this you need to add `-flto` to `CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`.